# Running ktor with a custom Configuration file via Gradle

Tags: kotlin, configuration, ktor

I have a simple Ktor application using `application.conf` files. [The documentation](https://ktor.io/docs/configurations.html#command-line) mentions that I can specify a custom configuration file to use as such :

[image]

Now, I would like to do exactly the same, except that I start my application using `./gradlew run`.

Using `./gradlew run -config=...` won't even run, while using `./gradlew run -Dconfig=...` seems to gloriously ignore the input I give it.

What is the proper way to provide a custom configuration time when starting my Ktor server with gradle?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, answering my own question after further research. The answer in this case is to run gradle as such :

`$./gradlew run --args="-config=src/main/resources/application.test.conf`

As per [the gradle documentation]([https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html#:~:text=Since%20Gradle%204.9%2C%20the%20command,setArgsString(java.)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html#:%7E:text=Since%20Gradle%204.9%2C%20the%20command,setArgsString(java.)).

Answer (score 1):

Supplement.

If you use idea to run a program, you can add the `-config` parameter to `Program arguments`.

e.g.
[image: e.g.image]